# AfterEffects Script for countdown from Source text

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm doing a script for a Countdown where it takes the `clockStart` text from the sourcetext of the layer. I can see the `clockStart` is getting the value by commenting the rest of the lines in the code. It shows me a value for `clockStart`.

```
rate = -1;
clockStart = thisComp.layer(1).text.sourceText.value;

function padZero(n){
if (n < 10) return "0" + n else return "" + n
}

clockTime = Math.max(clockStart + rate*(time - inPoint),0);

t = Math.floor(clockTime);
hours = Math.floor(t/3600)
min = Math.floor((t%3600)/60);
sec = Math.floor(t%60);
hours + ":" + min + ":" + padZero(sec)
```

As the timeline starts moving it shows me as NAN:NAN:NAN. But if put in a static value for clockStart such as `clockStart= 4500`. The countdown works. May I know where am I going wrong while fetching from the sourcetext

Comment: what would you get from `console.log(clockStart);` ?

Comment: I cant do console.log in Aftereffects, sorry im new to scripting in AfterEffects. Can you explain how to get that done, to see the console

Comment: try converting clockStart to `integer` using parseInt()

Comment: yes that works. post this as a comment so I can accept. Thanks

Comment: You need to learn the difference between expressions (what this is) and extendscript. https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/user-guide.html?topic=/after-effects/morehelp/automation.ug.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ouptput of following code is a NULL or a string.

```
clockStart = thisComp.layer(1).text.sourceText.value;
```

You have to convert it to integer so you can do mathematical calculations on it:

```
clockStart = thisComp.layer(1).text.sourceText.value;
clockStart = parseInt(clockStart);
```